# python non blocking write csv file

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

I am writing some python code to do some calculation and write the result to file. Here is my current code:

```py
for name, group in data.groupby('Date'):
    df = lot_of_numpy_calculations(group)

    with open('result.csv', 'a') as f:
        df.to_csv(f, header=False, index=False)
```

both calculation and write take sometimes. I read some article about async in python, but I didn't know how to implement it. Is there a easy way to optimize this loop so that it doesn't wait until the writing finish and start the next iteration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since neither numpy nor pandas io are asyncio aware, this might be a better use case for threads than for asyncio. (Also, asyncio based solutions will use threads behind the scenes anyway.)

For example, this code spawns a writer thread to which you submit work using a queue:

```
import threading, queue

to_write = queue.Queue()

def writer():
    # Call to_write.get() until it returns None
    for df in iter(to_write.get, None):
        with open('result.csv', 'a') as f:
            df.to_csv(f, header=False, index=False)
threading.Thread(target=writer).start()

for name, group in data.groupby('Date'):
    df = lot_of_numpy_calculations(group)
    to_write.put(df)
# enqueue None to instruct the writer thread to exit
to_write.put(None)
```

Note that, if writing turns out to be consistently slower than the calculation, the queue will keep accumulating data frames, which might end up consuming a lot of memory. In that case be sure to provide a maximum size for the queue by passing the `maxsize` argument to the [constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue).

Also, consider that re-opening the file for each write can slow down writing. If the amount of data written is small, perhaps you could get better performance by opening the file beforehand.

Comment: This is really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @JOHN I would also consider using a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor), or a [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) (in order to run the numpy computation in parallel).

Answer (score 1):

Since most operating systems [don't support](https://github.com/python/asyncio/wiki/ThirdParty#filesystem) asynchronous file I/O, common cross-platform approach now is to use threads.

For example, [aiofiles](https://github.com/Tinche/aiofiles) modules wraps thread pool to provide file I/O API for asyncio.